# Javascript eventListener keydown not working EVERY time I click

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that should execute each time i hit F9 or F10, but it only does so every other time I hit it?

I have an onchange event attached to the select box that is not firing every time I hit F9 or F10, just every other time or so.  I can tell by the ALERTS only firing every other time I hit the key.

What Gives?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        if( e.keyCode == '120' ){
            alert("yo");
            var curPosition = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').options.selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').selectedIndex =(curPosition-1);
            var invoice = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').value;
            getOrderToModify(invoice);
        }
        if( e.keyCode == '121' ){
            alert("gibear");
            var curPosition = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').options.selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').selectedIndex =(curPosition+1);
            var invoice = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').value;
            getOrderToModify(invoice);
        }
    }, false);
```

**Found the answer, it was to add:**

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // **put this line in your code**
        e.preventDefault(); // **put this line in your code**
        if( e.keyCode == '120' ){
        ...
```

Thank you **Rakesh Chouhan!**

Comment: But, it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/fubAk/

Comment: Don't use `alert` to debug. Amongst other things, it mucks about with focus, and if the document doesn't have focus, it won't receive the keydown event. Normally you want to use the debugger built into your browser to debug. For something like this, `console.log` may be useful (since single-stepping through the code or setting breakpoints may also take focus away).

Comment: F9 works every time for me, F10 once every two times.

Comment: Both work for me, every time. Perhaps you have some other event listener that stops the event bubbling?

Comment: hmm, i wonder if there is something wrong in my environment. Like too many windows open or something.

Comment: @user3225456 Na, my guess is it's browser related (I can replicate the problem in the console using a line or two of code) - something to do with the shortcut being used already/the focus being lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation(); // **put this line in your code**
    if( e.keyCode == '120' ){
        alert("yo");
        var curPosition = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').options.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').selectedIndex =(curPosition-1);
        var invoice = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').value;
        getOrderToModify(invoice);
    }
    if( e.keyCode == '121' ){
        alert("gibear");
        var curPosition = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').options.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').selectedIndex =(curPosition+1);
        var invoice = document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').value;
        getOrderToModify(invoice);
    }
}, false);
```

It will show the alert "gibear" once every two times because the F10 Key also registered with browser event so when you press F10 first time it shows the alert and then execute the browser event and set focus on browser event operation(ie. in firefox it shows the menu) but when you again press F10 it again focus back to the browser document. so when you press second time it focus back from the menu to your document.

To check this explanation when you press F10 first time click the page again and again press F10

Comment: Great Explanation! You must be a wizard. That worked...well it led me on to learn about stopPropagation AND that led me to **e.preventDefautl();** When I added both, **it worked flawlessly!**

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines where you're setting the new selectedIndex from this:

```
document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').selectedIndex =(curPosition-1);
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById('unpostedOrders').options.selectedIndex = (curPosition-1);
```

You where not accessing the options property which has the selectedIndex property.

Also you should check if the current position is less than zero or greater than the length of options